# When I click a row on main page, segues to next page, but does not display the context

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm using coredata to keep track of passwords, usernames, and titles. 
When I click the indexrowpath on the main page of all the titles, the labels set up to display the passwords do not show the passwords.

I also wanted to learn how to connect a variable or function from one file to the other. 
I don't think selectedPassword is connected, so I tried even using homeVC.selectedPassword?.item/username/password, but still did not work

PasswordVC

```
import UIKit

class Password: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var displayTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var displayUsername: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var displayPassword: UILabel!

    var homeVC = Home()
    var selectedPassword : PasswordCoreData?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        displayTitle.text = selectedPassword?.item
        displayUsername.text = selectedPassword?.username
        displayPassword.text = selectedPassword?.password
    }

}
```

From homeVC

```
var mainframe : [PasswordCoreData] = []
    var selectedPassword : PasswordCoreData?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        getPasswords()
    }

    func getPasswords() {
        if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {

            if let coreDataPasswords = try? context.fetch(PasswordCoreData.fetchRequest()) as? [PasswordCoreData] {
                mainframe = coreDataPasswords
                tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
    }



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mainframe.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = mainframe[indexPath.row].item

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {

                let item = mainframe[indexPath.row]
                context.delete(item)
                getPasswords()
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "seguePassword", sender: mainframe[indexPath.row].item)
    }
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let addVC = segue.destination as? addNewPassword {
            addVC.homeVC = self
        }

        if let passwordVC = segue.destination as? Password {

            if let selectedholder = sender as? PasswordCoreData {
                passwordVC.selectedPassword = selectedholder
                passwordVC.homeVC = self
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Replace first "var selectedPassword : PasswordCoreData?" with "var selectedPassword = PasswordCoreData()"

Comment: @BhavikModi what's the point of doing as you suggest? This will instantiate an empty object of PasswordCoreData, but he needs an object sent from the previous screen that has actual data inside. OP - show the code where you send the "sender" as PasswordCoreData. Might be that your object is empty and has nothing to show.

Comment: @Starsky I'm not too sure of your question, so I attached the entire homeVC. This is my first app, so please inform me if I'm even missing the section to do this

Comment: You are passing mainframe[indexpath.row].item as the sender in performSegue. This has type String, not type PasswordCoreData. Just pass mainframe[indexpath.row]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, edit your PasswordVC:

```
import UIKit

class Password: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var displayTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var displayUsername: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var displayPassword: UILabel!

    var selectedPassword : PasswordCoreData!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        displayTitle.text = selectedPassword?.item
        displayUsername.text = selectedPassword?.username
        displayPassword.text = selectedPassword?.password
    }
}
```

Secondly, prevent the segue to fire if your sender is not of type "PasswordCoreData":

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if identifier == "addNewPassword" || sender.isKind(of: PasswordCoreData.self) {
       return true
    }
    return false
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let addVC = segue.destination as? addNewPassword {
        addVC.homeVC = self //I don't understand why you're trying to pass on the viewController to another viewController?
    }

    if let passwordVC = segue.destination as? Password {

        if let selectedHolder = sender as? PasswordCoreData {
            passwordVC.selectedPassword = selectedholder
        }
    }
}
```

Thirdly, pass the corect object as a sender:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "seguePassword", sender: mainframe[indexPath.row]) //not the item, but the whole object
}
```

Comment: Awesome, works :) Thanks!
in the "secondly" code section, It brings up three errors: Closure expression is unused, Expected expression, and Expected expression after operator. It works with that part of the code commented out, but I understand you want to guarantee it fulfills all conditions

Comment: Not sure where you get the error. Can you make a screenshot and share the image here? Maybe use imgur.com or something similar.

Comment: Why do you have ";" sign after "PassworCoreData" ? Check the line 72 in your code. Remove it and it should be fine. In Swift we don't use ";" sign. Stop using it. It is much cleaner and prettier without it :)

Comment: It showed an error without it. Still has the other three errors
https://imgur.com/a/UIeJQi6

Comment: Okay, I made a mistake in that function. My apologies. Please see the edited code.

Comment: No worries, thanks for updating the code! Only one error this time. https://imgur.com/a/OHvSLGT. And I'm passing the VC to have the arrays and variables available in the other VCs

Comment: I am so sorry for this mess. I was writing without checking it in Xcode. This time it should be fine, but it can also yell regarding Optional. You will want to deal with it (force-unwrap or provide a default value).

Comment: unwrap which section? because PasswordCoreData is already unwrapped in passwordVC